# cfchart ignores my scalefrom value

Tags: coldfusion, cfchart

I have the following codes in my page.

The style variable holds the custom style.

```
  <cfchart chartheight="450" chartwidth="550" gridlines="9"   yaxistitle="Score" scalefrom="20" scaleto="100" style="#style#"   format="png" >
         <cfchartseries query="variables.chart_query" type="scatter"   seriescolor="##000000" itemcolumn="MyItem" valuecolumn="MyScore"/>
     </cfchart>
```

Before I begin, please see [chart_good.jpg](http://www.monteandjanicechan.com/chart_good.jpg).  This is how I want my report to come up.  On the x-axis, there will always be three items as long as at least one of them has values.  If an item does not have any values (i.e. 2010), there would not be a marker in the chart.

The problem occurs only when only one item has value.  Please see [chart_bad.jpg](http://www.monteandjanicechan.com/chart_bad.jpg).  As you can see, 2008 and 2010 do not have any values; y-axis is now scaled from 0 to 100.  I have tried setting one of the items (ex. 2008) a value of 0 or something off the chart; it would scale according to this off-the-chart value and the 2009 value.  In short, I have to have at least two items with values between 20 and 100 in order for cfchart to scale from 20 to 100.

My question is, how can I correct the issue so that cfchart would ALWAYS scale from 20 to 100?  I am running CF9.

Comment: What happens when 2008 has a value, but 2010 does not?  Same thing?

Comment: Yes, the same thing happened.

Comment: Can you post a cfdump of variables.chart_query?

Comment: here is the cfdump
http://www.monteandjanicechan.com/cfdump.jpg

Answer (score 0):

What is inside your style variable?

I would suggest not using scaleFrom="" and scaleTo="" in the cfchart tag as they can be buggy sometimes.  I believe that Coldfusion's cfchart tag attempts to scale the chart **automatically** to what it deems the best fit.  Instead I would build the chart's minimum and maximum scales inside a frameChart tag.

Example of a style variable to build a chart

```
<cfsavecontent variable="style">
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <frameChart is3D="false" font="Arial-11-bold">
    <frame xDepth="0" yDepth="0" outline="black" lightColor="#CCCCCC" darkColor="#CCCCCC"
            wallColor="#CCCCCC" frameSize="5" dashSize="3" gridColor="#333333">
        <background type="HorizontalGradient" maxColor="#828EB0"/>
    </frame>



    <!---  THE BREAD AND BUTTER 
           NOTE: if you use variables for the scaleMin and scaleMax
           make sure to surround them with a cfoutput tag
    --->

    <yAxis scaleMin="20" scaleMax="100">
    <!--- --------------------- --->

        <labelFormat style="Currency" pattern="#,##0"/>
        <parseFormat pattern="#,##0"/>
        <titleStyle></titleStyle>
    </yAxis>

    <legend allowSpan="true" isVisible="false" placement="Bottom" valign="Bottom" foreground="black"
            isMultiline="true">
        <decoration style="None"/>
    </legend>

    <elements outline="black" shapeSize="40"/>
    <popup background="#748BA6" foreground="white"/>
    <paint palette="Modern" paint="Plain" isVertical="true"/>
    <insets right="5"/>

   </frameChart>

</cfsavecontent>
```

Then all you have to do is load the variable into the style attribute like you already mentioned.

```
<cfchart format="png" chartWidth="550" chartHeight="175" style="#style#">
```

Also a great resource to use, is the Webcharts program that will be in your C:/coldfusion/charting/ directory.  Just open **webcharts.bat**, create your custom chart, copy the xml code into your style variable, and voila!

Make sure to remove the scaleTo= and scaleFrom= from your cfchart tag if you decide to go this route.